# Indefinite integral of $\int x\sqrt{x-1} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

How can I evaluate the indefinite integral $$\int x\sqrt{x-1} \, \mathrm dx?$$

I tried to calculate it using integration by parts, 
I get 
$$\int x\sqrt{x-1} \, \mathrm dx = \frac{2}{3}x(x-1)^{3/2} - \frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot(x-1)^{5/2}$$

But this is not the correct solution, and I don't understand why.

In the integration by parts formula I used $f(x)=x$ and $g'(x)=(x-1)^{1/2}$
so $f'(x)=1$ and $g(x)=(x-1)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}$.

What did I do wrong? I know I should use substitutional integral, but why does my solution not work? Thank you

Comment: Don't forget your $+C$!

Comment: Your answer is correct though. Take a derivative and you'll see it. You just have it written in a different form that one might expect. That does not make it any less valid.

Comment: Except for the Thought-Police-required "+C" - which really is required - your answer is OK. Why do you think your answer is wrong? To check, differentiate your putative anti-derivative. You do get the integrand back, so you're fine....The "+C" can make answers that look different be the same. What is the answer that you expected?

Comment: Oops @CameronWilliams was faster than I.

Comment: Thank you Cameron Williams :), after some algebraic manipulation I got the same result as I gained by checking in the internet, which was (2/3)*(x-1)^1.5+(6/15)*(x-1)^2.5   And of course, I forgot the C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$I = \int x\sqrt{x-1}dx = \int (x-1+1)\sqrt{x-1}dx = \int[(x-1)^{3/2} + (x-1)^{1/2}]dx$

$$I =\frac{2}{5}(x-1)^{5/2} + \frac{2}{3}(x-1)^{3/2} +c $$

or

$$I = \frac{2}{15}\cdot(x-1)^{3/2}(3x+2)+c$$

Comment: Thank you Ak19, great solution!

Comment: You're welcome:)

Answer (score 4):

Another method can be done by substitution as:
Substitite $(x-1) = u^2$
That gives $ x =  u^2+1$
And $$dx = 2udu$$
The integral becomes $\int {2 u^2(u^2+1)} du  $
And its integration is $ \frac {2u^3}{15} [3u^2+5] +C$
After substituting the value of $u^2=x-1$ you get
$$\frac{ 2(x-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{15}[3x+2] +C $$

Comment: Thank you Vedant Chourney, your solution is the third possible one!